# Can you make an external iterator interface for this internal iterator?

Tags: rust, control-flow

I am using "external" and "internal" following [this article](https://medium.com/@veedrac/rust-is-slow-and-i-am-the-cure-32facc0fdcb). Say I am writing multi-column text rendering library: Each column should write its next line to the output in a round-robin fashion. I want to write a trait for columns (e.g. to have columns with different justification) such that this round-robin writing is ensured.

It is not hard to write this as an "internal" iterator that gives or "pushes" the writer for the next line to the columns, see the example below. However, it would be nicer to present an "external" iterator that lets each column "pull" all the line writers it needs.

```
struct LineWriter;

trait Column {
    // With an API similar to this one, I can guarantee that columns write to
    // lines in the correct order (by adding a return value that proves that the
    // line was written, but I omitted that for simplicity).
    fn write_to_line(&self, line: &mut LineWriter);
    // But I would prefer an interface similar to this for Columns:
    // fn write(&self, it: impl Iterator<Item=LineWriter>);
}

struct SomeColumn;

impl Column for SomeColumn {
    fn write_to_line(&self, line: &mut LineWriter) { todo!() }
}

fn main() {
    let cols = vec![SomeColumn, SomeColumn];

    for line_number in 0..100 {
        let mut line_writer = LineWriter;
        for w in &cols {
            w.write_to_line(&mut line_writer);
        }
    }

    // In the preferred version, this would become
    // for w in &cols {
    //    let line_writer_it = ??? to be determined ???
    //    w.write(line_writer_it);
    // }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8037ca0ca50207302c8adb085e5fc1d1)

If we can control how columns are called (i.e. `main()` in this example) and what the `LineWriter` struct or its iterator look like, is there a way to have an internal iterator interface that has this guarantee? I think writing to other lines would need to happen in the iterator's `next()` function. But thinking along these lines, I got stuck because it would only ever to go deeper in the call stack, and never return from `next()` – how could it resume with writing the second line of the first column after writing the first line of the second column?. Perhaps the solution involves an iterator of `impl Future<LineWriter>`? Of course buffering the lines as `Vec<String>` or so and later writing them in an interleaved fashion is possible, but not what I'm interested in.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow. Are you asking how to make a custom iterator around `(0..100).flat_map(|_| &cols)` essentially?

Comment: @vallentin I'd like to know how to make the trait work with the commented-out function instead of the current one. What would need to be done in the iterator and in the calling code to get round-robin behavior?

Comment: Could you add an example to the question, with desired input/output, or maybe try to show "how" you'd like to _be able_ to call `write()`. Because I'm not entirely sure how to correctly connect the dots, when you have `cols` and create a new `LineWriter` for every `0..100`.

Comment: So you want each column to be able to do something like `line_writers_iter.zip(lines).for_each(|writer, line| writer.write(line))`, without the columns having to care about synchronizing with other columns, and without buffering the data in the `LineWriter`s?

Comment: @zale pretty much something like that could be how a column instance implements write(), and yes, without synchronizing and buffering

Comment: @vallentin, I added commented out code showing the general shape of the calling code. How I'd produce the iterator is part of the solution, so I can't tell yet.